# ItemsControl + UniformGrid: Display custom class in each cell

Tags: wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol

I'm trying to display every `Block` (my custom class with some more properties) of the `GameBoard.BlockList` in a seperate cell of the uniform grid.

This way there will be just a `Common.XY.Block` string be displayed, which I understand. Block is not an `UIElement`.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding GameBoard.BlockList}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <UniformGrid Background="Transparent" Rows="{Binding GameBoard.Rows}" Columns="{Binding GameBoard.Columns}" Margin="1,1,1,1"/>                   
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>            
</ItemsControl>
```

So I thought I could use as a `DataTemplate` soemthing like this:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
      <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Drop="Rectangle_Drop" AllowDrop="True" Width="50" Height="50"/>                  
     </Border>
   </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

This will add in each cell of the `UniformGrid` a `Rectangle`, surrounded by a `Border`, but I don't have access to my custom block.

I don't know exactly how to achieve my goal here. I want to use the `GameBoard` as the "main source" where I store data and work with it.

How do I have to use the `UniformGrid` to keep its felxiblity with the `ItemsControl` one the one side and use all data of the `GameBoard` on the other side?

Comment: The DataContext of the Border and the Rectangle in the ItemTemplate will be a Block object from the ItemsSource of the ItemsControl. You can bind to any of its properties in the ItemTemplate as usual. The ItemTemplate defines the appearance of each Block.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. To paint a picture: my block object conatins the border and the border contains the rectangle? And how do I access this now from code?

Comment: You access the Block objects in the class where the source collection is defined. i.e. in the view model. The view and the XAML markup should only define the *appearance* of a Block. Nothing else.

Comment: @mm8 Yes, makes sense. But the Rectangle and the Block doesn't have a commection, right? They just share the same cell of the uniformgrid? And is their a way to access a list of the uniformgrid where I can see what each cell contains? And which Row and Column it is?

Answer (score 3):

This example can show you the correct path. You should set `ItemContainerStyle` and Bind Grid.Row and Grid.Column properties of the Blocks in it. You should use `ItemTemplate` to use the properties of each Block into one or mode UIElements.

```
  <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding GameBoard}" ItemsSource="{Binding BlockList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Background="Transparent" 
                             Rows="{Binding GameBoard.Rows}" 
                             Columns="{Binding GameBoard.Columns}" Margin="1,1,1,1"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Background}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The ViewModel is your GameBoard. It should have number of Total rows and columns of the Uniform Grid and also an ObservableCollection, filled with the Blocks:

```
public class GameBoard : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public GameBoard()
    {
        var m1 = new Block() { Name = "b1", Background = Brushes.Red, Col=0, Row = 0 };
        var m2 = new Block() { Name = "b2", Background = Brushes.Gray, Col=0, Row = 0 };
        var m3 = new Block() { Name = "b3", Background = Brushes.Goldenrod, Col=0, Row = 0 };
        var m4 = new Block() { Name = "b4", Background = Brushes.Honeydew, Col=0, Row = 0 };

        _blockList = new ObservableCollection<Block>() { m1, m2, m3, m4 }; 
    }

    int _rows = 2;
    public int Rows { get { return _rows; } set { _rows = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Rows"); } }

    int _cols = 2;
    public int Columns { get { return _cols; } set { _cols = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Columns"); } }

    ObservableCollection<Block> _blockList;
    public ObservableCollection<Block> BlockList { get { return _blockList; } set { _blockList = value; RaisePropertyChanged("BlockList"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void RaisePropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }
}
```

Your Model should have different information about the pieces, for example their name, Color, Position (Row and Column) and etc.

```
public class Block : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    int _row;
    public int Row { get { return _row; } set { _row = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Row"); } }

    int _col;
    public int Col { get { return _col; } set { _col = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Col"); } }

    string _name;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); } }

    Brush _background;
    public Brush Background { get { return _background; } set { _background = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Background"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void RaisePropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }


}
```

and at last, you should set the DataContext properly:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        GameBoard = new GameBoard(); 
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
    public GameBoard GameBoard { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! That's almost how I did it. One question regarding the `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle`: I know that this is the `ContentPresenter`, but why do you set `Row`s and `Column`s there? And where do you get them from for the binding?